# Reverse Depth Mask Shader

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, depth-buffer, depth-testing

***I am developing in Unity3D.***

Using the Depth Mask shader defined [here](http://pixelplacement.com/2011/02/15/masking-in-unity/), objects behind the mask using the shader are not drawn (only objects in front of the mask are drawn). Using the referenced code, I attempted to create a *reverse Depth Mask*, which is intended to cause the camera to **only draw objects behind it**.

What I did was change

```
ZTest LEqual
```

into

```
ZTest GEqual
```

I also tried

```
ZTest Greater
```

However, what happens is that the camera draws all objects, be it behind or in front of the mask. **How do I implement a reverse depth mask?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `ZTest GEqual` in the shader of the masked object, not the mask itself. Also note that the depth mask and the masked objects have to be rendered *before* all other objects. So you should use the following render queues:

- Depth mask: `Geometry - 20` or `2080`
- Masked objects: `Geometry - 10` or `2090`

(A more detailed description of depth masks can be found in the [Unity Wiki](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DepthMask).)

You should also disable z-buffer writes for the masked objects (`ZWrite Off`). This means that if the masked objects overlap, they won't render correctly. You'll probably also run into problems with the rest of the geometry. A better approach is to use stencil buffers which are available in the Pro version of Unity 4.2.

Comment: To clarify, does this mean I'm using a correct mask shader and that I just need to create a masked object shader? I mean should the mask shader retain its `ZTest LEqual` setting? Thanks!

Comment: I did some reading on Stencil Buffers, it appears that I was approaching the problem using the wrong technique. Stencil buffers seems to provide what I'll be needing. Thanks.